# Shrink img without losing quality?

Tags: html, css

See this:

http://real-sense.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=106

The set of vertical images on the right are being resized using CSS

```
.thumbnail-product-resize
{
width:144px;
height : auto;
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this in a cleaner way so I don't lose quality on the image?

I mean that if I had resized the image using photoshop, the text won't appear as blurry as it does here.

Tested in FF

Thanks

Comment: I think it is self explanatory what resize refers to here.

Comment: That's the 'same thing' I meant and everyone else understood it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The quality of your images will depend on the original size of the image you use. If have a large image with good quality, say of size `400x500`, and it is then resized in the HTML to `80x100`, it will still be a `400x500` image. However you can only fit a certain number of pixels on a smaller image of `80x100`, so this bigger image has to be sampled. This means that an average is taken of pixels and then made to represent a `80x100` size image.
If you want a more definite result you can change to original size of the image to `80x100`. This will probably give you better results.

Comment: Hi Tom, you mentioned how the resolution won't change, although the pixels get "averaged" to fit inside the 80x100 size. If you zoom in on the 80x100 image, will the image appear as clear as the original 400x500 photo, or will it carry its 80x100 resolution?

Answer (score 4):

Once upon a time browser image resizing gave truly heinous results due to the unsophisticated [nearest neighbor technique](http://tech-algorithm.com/articles/nearest-neighbor-image-scaling/) they used to scale images.  Now they usually perform filtering when scaling and there isn't **that** much difference between in-browser resizing and resizing in Photoshop.

The real advantage to scaling an image before serving it to the client is that you aren't forcing the download of large images when they aren't necessary.  Depending on the size of your images, this can significantly reduce your page load times.

One final thing to consider is that more and more people have devices with "retina" displays.  For those users scaling the image before serving it will result in much less crisp images.

*Here's an in-depth comparison of the image scaling methods used by various browsers: http://entropymine.com/resamplescope/notes/browsers/*

Answer (score 3):

Even if you had done this in photoshop those images you have would still appear pretty much the way do just now.

FYI you don't need to include height:auto in your CSS above.

Best bet would be to create a seperate set of thumbnails (using photoshop) which maybe just show a portion of the image.

Loading the thumbnails and resizing them with css the way you are doing is bad practice as you are still having the user download the large images first.

Comment: The term for making thumbnails by having the browser resize the full image is "dumbnails".

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to shrink an image without loosing quality unless it is an vector-image. That would mean that you'd have to use SVG. And considering the images displayed I don't think you wan't to do that.

Also you mentioned the cleaner way to do it, use photoshop or something similar.

Comment: SVG would lose quality in the same way in this instance, it's still rendering to a raster based output with fewer pixels.

Comment: @DA thats true, I was unclear in my answer. Thanks for pointing that out, what I meant was that it's only possible to shrink vector images without loss of information.

Comment: You can scale up SVG without losing crispness, but scaling down will result in less definition whether it's a raster or a vector image.

Comment: @ChrisHerbert true but that is because of the fact that screens have pixels not because the image itself, or rather the image format contains less information.

Comment: @Daniel Figueroa - yes, that's true.  But for the purposes of this question, both an SVG image and a very large raster image will work equally well.